# java msql insert record to table

Tags: java, mysql

I'm trying add record to database . I can't find mistake in this function . anyone can help ?

```
public static void insertTable(int idEmployee , String First_Name , String Last_Name , String Password , int Sex , String Mail , int Employee_idEmployee ) throws Exception  {

        Connection conn = (Connection) getConnection() ;
        try {
            PreparedStatement insertStatement = (PreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO employee (?,?,?,?,?,?,?) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            insertStatement.setInt(1, idEmployee);
            insertStatement.setString(2, First_Name);
            insertStatement.setString(3, Last_Name );
            insertStatement.setString(4, Password);
            insertStatement.setInt(5, Sex);
            insertStatement.setString(6, Mail);
            insertStatement.setInt(7 ,Employee_idEmployee);

            insertStatement.close(); 
            conn.close() ; 

            System.out.println("it's ok");

        } catch (SQLException e) {

            System.out.println(e.getMessage());

        }       
    }
```

and in Main

```
insertTable(4 , "test" , "test" , "test" , 1 , "test" , 4 );
```

this is prtSc table :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fScns.png)

Comment: you have to specify column names instead of question marks for first group of question marks

Comment: either you would have to remove `?` from `INSERT INTO employee (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)` here or you would need to add column names instead of `?`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifying column names is part of the fix.

You are still missing the execution line

you have no `insertStatement.execute();` call

Comment: Thanks a lot ! program still is not working but now i have error so is better

Comment: is it because your Sex Column is specified as a BOOL?

Comment: this column is okej , my problem was with foreign key but now evrything is okej ! thanks again man ! you was very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I think I found what your error is.

Instead of the following:

```
"INSERT INTO employee (?,?,?,?,?,?,?) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
```

Try this

```
"INSERT INTO employee (Your DB Variables)VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
```

An example is this 
The "DB" I am using has two variables(Name,ID)
String Name
int ID

```
 PreparedStatement insertStatement = (PreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO DB (Name,ID) VALUES (?,?)");
insertStatement.setString(1,Name);
insertStatement.setInt(2,ID);
insertStatement.execute();
System.out.println("Success!");
```

Where it say your DB variables, put in the variable/column names in. The question mark is for variable use only.

I am assuming you are using ucanaccess?

Let me know!

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The only other thing I can think of is you data types. I had the same issues with my ms access DB. Check your data types.